# OO design problem

Tags: oop

Suppose there's 2 classes : `A` and `B`.

`A` can operate on `B`.

I need to be able to query all `B` instances that `A` has operated on.

And for a specific `B` instance, I need to be able to query all `A` instances that have operated on it.

What's the elegant(in the OO taste..) solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: It depends on what language you are using, but in theory you can create some kind of list, and every time an event is fired in which A operates on B you add to that list. The same goes for the other situation.

Comment: Sound like observer pattern to me. If you use Java, maybe you need to extend some classes/interfaces

Answer (score 1):

In a language like Java I would do something like:

```
package com.whatever.blah;

public class A {
    private Set<B> patients = new HashSet<B>;

    public void operateOn(B patient) {
        patient.startRecoveringFromOperation(this);
        patients.add(patient);
    }

    public List<B> getPatients() {
        return patients;
    }
}

public class B {
    private Set<A> surgeons = new HashSet<A>;

    //this has package access to `A` can access it but other classes can't
    void startRecoveringFromOperation(A theSurgeon) {
        surgeons.add(theSurgeon);
    }

    public List<A> getSurgeons() {
        return surgeons;
    }
}
```

This really isn't doing anything special, beyond using [package access](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to allow `A` access to `B`'s `startRecoveringFromOperation()` method while hiding the method from most other classes.  In other languages you might use a different approach to accomplish this.  For instance in C++ you might declare `A` as a `friend` of `B` instead.

Comment: It seems you're duplicating the data... Is is the most elegant design? BTW I don't see where's `b` defined..

Comment: @new_perl - That `b` was a typo, it should have been `patient` (fixed now).  I can't say if this is the most elegant design, as that would depend upon exactly what you want to accomplish with it.  This is just one possible solution to the problem.  It does store some redundant data to simplify the logic of finding every `A` for a given `B`.  And yes, this only allows you to operate on `B` by going through `A`, because I assumed that was the desired usage pattern.  If this doesn't suit your designs, you can of course modify it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class A {
    void operate(B b) {
        operatedOn.add(b);
        b.operatedOnBy.add(this);
    }
    final Set<B> operatedOn = new HashSet<B>();
}
class B {
    final Set<A> operatedOnBy = new HashSet<A>();
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a=new A();
        B b=new B();
        a.operate(b);
        System.out.println(a+" "+a.operatedOn);
        System.out.println(b+" "+b.operatedOnBy);
    }
}
```